# What is the meaning of "I’d really like to get this project behind us"

Tags: meaning-in-context

"I’d really like to get this project behind us"

Get this project finish fast
Or
Ignore the project
Or 
Other meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> get this project behind us

Let's break this down.

> behind us

In this instance, "behind" means "behind in time" and "us" is referring to the present, so this means "in the past".

> get this project

This definition of "get" is the fifth listed [on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Verb):

> (transitive) To cause to become; to bring about.

Thus, "get this project behind us" means "cause the project to be in the past". Ignoring the project doesn't really cause it to have been in the past, but having already done it *does* cause it to have been in the past, which means that your sentence can be reworded:

> I'd really like to finish this project soon.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic expression is: to get something behind [you or us or them or me or him or her]

It means **to be finished with something or to have completed it**.

If you walk down the street and a thing is then behind you, you have passed it.